# Does the analytic continuation of $f$ always exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic funtion on region $\Omega$. Then, does the analytic continuation of $f$ always exist? Note that $f$ is always the analytic continuation of itself, so I exclude this case.

If the answer is yes, then what is the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, defined on the unit disk?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytic continuation does not always exist. The region $\Omega$ could be "maximal" in that sense.

In case of $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, the continuation exists on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 1 \}$ and is $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ as mentioned in a comment to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$$
has no analytic continuation beyond $|z|<1$. The circle $|z|=1$ is a [natural boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Natural_boundary).

Comment: Yes. Your link also refers the Wikipedia page [lacunary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) with more information.