# Does every Dirichlet series admit an analytic continuation? If so, to what extent?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

The [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) for analytic continuation shows that *uniqueness* of analytic continuations of functions is very easy to characterize. This helps us a lot when we are trying to extend functions like the Riemann zeta function or the gamma function.

However, examples [such as the one in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921384) show that *existence* of analytic continuations of functions is not so easy. My question is, given a Dirichlet series
$$ F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}} $$
defined on a half-plane $\text{Re }s > \sigma_{0}$ for some $\sigma_{0}$, does $F$ necessarily admit a complex-analytic extension to a larger domain? If so, what is the largest domain to which we can extend $F$?

My dubious conjecture is that if $F$ is well-defined on a half-plane, then it admits a meromorphic extension to all of $\mathbb{C}$, but I don't know if this is really true. Is this reasonable or not? How can I determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, meromorphic continuation is definitely too much to ask for, as the example $\log \zeta(s) = \sum_{p^r} \frac1r \frac1{(p^r)^s}$ shows: it has logarithmic singularities at $s=1$ and at every zero of $\zeta(s)$.

Even a continuation with branch cuts cannot necessarily extend to $\Bbb C$: the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function#Properties) is an example of a Dirichlet series with the imaginary axis as its natural boundary.

I think that in a suitable sense, "most" Dirichlet series have its line of convergence as a natural boundary (in other words, no merormophic extension at all!). I couldn't find a clean statement to this effect, but you can look for example at some [work of Bhowmik and Shlage-Puchta from 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3370).

Answer (score 2):

Look at $$F(s)=\prod_{n\ge 2} (1-n^{-ns+1})$$
It converges and it is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$ and its zeros are at $$\Omega=\{  \frac{2i\pi k}{n\log n}+\frac{1}{n}, k\in \Bbb{Z}, n\ge 2\}$$
Every point of $i\Bbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $\Omega$,
so $F$ can't extend analytically to any point of the imaginary axis.